# I want to be able to extract two different sequences from one line

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop

I want to be able to extract two different sequences from one line.

For example:

**atg** ttg tca aat tca tgg atc *atg* ttg tca aat tca tgg atc **tag**

I want to create a loop where the program will read from the 1st **atg** to **tag**, output that sequence into a file, as well as take the second *atg* read to **tag**, output that sequence into the same file.

Output I want:

```
atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc tag
atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc tag
```

How can I go about this?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What will be the output? What have you tried?

Comment: Ideally, the output would be: atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc tag &  atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc tag. I am a beginner using bash. I haven't tried anything because I do not know how to approach the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
str="atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc tag"
start="atg"    # start marker of the sequence
end="tag"      # end marker of the sequence

read -r -a ary <<< "$str"
for (( i=0; i<${#ary[@]}; i++ )); do
    if [[ ${ary[$i]} = $start ]]; then
        index_s+=("$i")
    elif [[ ${ary[$i]} = $end ]]; then
        index_e+=("$i")
    fi
done

s=${index_s[0]}; n=$(( ${index_e[0]} - ${index_s[0]} + 1 ))
echo "${ary[@]:$s:$n}" > "result.txt"
s=${index_s[1]}; n=$(( ${index_e[0]} - ${index_s[1]} + 1 ))
echo "${ary[@]:$s:$n}" >> "result.txt"
```

Result:

```
atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc tag
atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc tag
```

**[How it works]**

- `read -r -a ary <<< "$str"` splits `$str` on whitespaces (IFS) and
  stores the elements into an array `ary`.
- Then the `for` loop iterates over the array elements for the start/end
  markers.
- If the start marker `atg` is found, the position is stored in an array
  `index_s`.
  Finally `${index_s[0]}` holds the first position of the start marker and
  `${index_s[1]}` holds the second one (and so on).
  The same operation is performed with the end marker `tag`.
- Eventually the script outputs two sets of array slice. One starts with
  the first `atg` and ends with the first `tag`. The other starts with
  the second `atg` and ends with the first `tag`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you want at most 2 sequences, you can `grep` inside the original and a modified string:

```
s='atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc tag'
printf "%s\n" "$s" "${s#*atg}" | grep -Eo "atg.*tag"
```

When you want to extract more than 2 substrings when available, you need a loop.

```
s='atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc atg ttg tca aat tca tgg atc tag'
while [ "$s" ]; do
   s=$(grep -Eo "atg.*tag" <<< "$s")
   if [ "$s" ]; then
      echo "$s"
      s="${s#atg}"
   fi
done
```